CMake project with zephyr
A quick question about CMake(I'm beginner with it) My environment :
MyApp
  |------ CMakeLists.txt (The main Cmake)
  |------ src
  |          |----- main.c
  |          |----- i2c
  |                    |------- i2c_file.c        
  |                    |------- CmakeLists.txt here or not ??  
  |          |----- otherfolder
  |                    |------- file.c        
  |                    |------- CmakeLists.txt here or not ??  
  |------- driver
  |          |----- driver.c
  |          |----- CmakeLists.txt here or not ??  
  |------ build

My question is about i2c folder what is the best way to add it with CMake ? Use separate CMakeLists inside the folder or add it directly to main CMakeLists ? Knowing that I will have several folders of the i2c type with multiple file.
